# Azure Cognitive Search find similar documents use case

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

Please help me understand if what I am trying to do is possible to implement with Azure Cognitive Search.

I have a bunch of PDF files extracted and indexed as text (so I don't use the OCR build-in feature for the index, I prepare extracted PDF data with third-party tools) and I need somehow implement the feature called "find me similar documents in the index based on a new one document".
So as an input parameter for the search, I pass the extracted PDF text (that usually looks like a mess with new line symbols) that I want to use to find similar extracted PDF files in my index. That means they have a similar structure/company names/people etc.
Is that possible to do? I can't find any similar cases described in the documentation, but I assume it could be somehow configured with a full query search.

Please advise me am I moving in the right direction at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two possible ways:

1-Implement an enrichment process during the injection that will pre classify the content.

2-you use the semantic search feature and rely on it to return documents that are similar and relevant to the content you're searching for.

**EDIT**

I just noticed, there's a new feature called 'moreLikeThis' which is current in preview mode, but I believe it's what you're looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-more-like-this

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-search-overview

https://youtu.be/d_6ZNyV1MvA?t=619

Comment: thanks for the answer!
but even if I implement an enrichment, how can I pass the text to the search and get similar documents in classification?
I can definitely add it to the index, and then it will have a classification. but what about searching without adding?

Comment: with my first approach, you'll need to know the possible categories in advance, then when performing the search, you boost by 'category' for example. If you can't do that, the only possible way is doing the second approach.

Comment: check the part I edit in my answer